# Python: reshaping parallel arrays into training set

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have two parallel arrays, created using *meshgrid*:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
```

Now I would like to convert it into **(Xn * Yn, 2)-shaped** training set for NN:

```
[[x_1, y_1], [x_2, y_2], ..., [x_m, y_m]]

(where m = Xn * Yn)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: np.stack((X, Y), axis=-1) ?

Comment: @MaxChrétien I makes (Xn, Yn, 2)-shaped array — not what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `reshape` and `stack`, use `reshape` function to convert X and Y to one column 2D array *((Xn, 1) for X, (Yn, 1) for Y)* firstly and then stack them horizontally:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid([1,2], [3,4,5])    
np.hstack([X.reshape(-1, 1), Y.reshape(-1, 1)])

#array([[1, 3],
#       [2, 3],
#       [1, 4],
#       [2, 4],
#       [1, 5],
#       [2, 5]])
```

Or another option as mentioned by @Denis:

```
np.stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel()), axis=-1)
```

As for the speed, the two options are comparable:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1000), np.arange(1000))

%timeit np.hstack([X.reshape(-1, 1), Y.reshape(-1, 1)])
#100 loops, best of 3: 4.77 ms per loop

%timeit np.stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel()), axis=-1)
#100 loops, best of 3: 4.89 ms per loop
```

Comment: Works fine. Will *XY_train = np.stack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel()), axis=-1)* be an equivalent?